# DiscordJS: add role to array of user

Tags: javascript, discord.js

Playing with a giveaway script i want to have it adding roles to each winner. I know i most likely will have to convert User into a guildMember - but unsure how to do it in this case.

DiscordJS 12

```
manager.on("giveawayEnded", async (giveaway, winners) => {
    const role = await giveaway.message.guild.roles.create({ data: { name: "Giveaway" } });
    - console.log(role.id); // returns the correct role ID from the rank created above -
        winners.forEach((winner) => winner.roles.add(role.id));
});
```

**returns**:

```
(node:12708) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property 'add' of undefined
- for- 
winners.forEach((winner) => winner.roles.add(role.id));
```

This is the output of console.log(winnners)
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you've speculated, you need to convert your `User` into a `GuildMember`. This is because `User`s have no `.roles` property, since they represent a Discord user that isn't specific to any server.

Fortunately this is simple:

```
winners.forEach(winner => giveaway.message.guild.member(winner).roles.add(role.id))
```

By using the `Guild.member(user)` function you can convert a `User` to a `GuildMember`. Be aware that if one of your winners left during the giveaway the function might return null - you'll likely want to add a filter or a condition for that.

Comment: Oh god, i see - its actually quite simple.

I've been toying around with 10 different solutions - and i believe i maybe ended up looknig myself blind on it. 

I did a quick test for myself, and it seemed to work - now I've opened up a test giveaway with 5 winners to see if all users get the role added!

Thank you so much for your quick input - i will mark it as the solution once its confirmed 100% working.